# How do i get an array instead of an object using mongoose?

Tags: arrays, mongoose

i use Mongoose to get my data from my database with this get function.

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res)=> {
  const products = await Product.findOne({slug: req.params.id});
  if (products) {
    res.send(products);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({message:"product not found"})
  } 
});
```

The output seems to be an object. However i need a array instead, because i use the slice() method in my further code.

What i tried: var ready = Object.keys(products).map((key) => [Number(key), products[key]]);

Is there any function i could use to make an array instead of the object or another mongoose function for getting an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier approach would be to use `find` as it always returns an array. In your case:

```
const products = await Product.findslug: req.params.id});
```

Also note that `if (products) {` would now always return `true`, so you may want to update to `if (products.length) {` (in case you need at least 1 document).

---

There's also `aggregate` method available that also returns an array but usually it's being used for a little more advanced queries. If your query is as simple as you have provided, you don't need `aggregate` here.

Comment: lel theres always a simple approach..
Thank you!